# Error in consuming https web service even after disabling trust manager

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting below error even after disabling the **TrustManager**

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Below is the code I am using to consumer web service.

```
public class HttpsDisable {


public static void disableCertificateValidation() {
      TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
          public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
        }
      };
      try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }


public static void main(String[] args)  {


                //Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the truststore
                try {
                 disableCertificateValidation();
                 URL url = new URL("https://162.19.122.114/service.asmx?wsdl");
                 System.out.println("url ================ "+url);

                 String sWebserviceurl = "https://172.17.134.214/service.asmx?wsdl";
                 String sXMLInput = "<KeedAn><PrAge>26</PrAge></KeedAn>";
                    AnalysisServiceService sl = new AnalysisServiceServiceLocator();
                    AnalysisService service =  sl.getAnalysisService(new URL(sWebserviceurl));
                    String in = service.getNeedProdRes(sXMLInput);
                    System.out.println("web service output ----------\n" + in);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}   
}
```

Can you please tell me where am I going wrong, since the above code is not working and throws above exception. And I have also save the .cert file in jre/lib/.cert path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, It will disable and print response in console,

```
String send = "https://www.example.com";
        URL url = new URL(send);
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
        {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            {
            }
        } };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        IOUtils.copy(url.openStream(), System.out);
```

Comment: I got java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be. Please advise.

Comment: Plz tell Which IDE you use.. Or use System.out.print(url.openStream()); insteadof IOUtils.copy(url.openStream(), System.out);

Comment: I am using Eclispe Juno. But when I ping the above webservice ip address using command prompt I am getting request time out. But when I hit the same from browser I get the page of xml and also there is no proxy configured for the webservice url .i.e. I am not using any proxy for this particular ip. And also please note the SSL certificate is expired will that affect in consuming web service. Any how we will renew the certificate.

Comment: same error even after changing to System.out.print(url.openStream()).

Comment: It sounds like Proxy Problem , check your proxy nothing wrong with code. Browser will automatically detect proxy but terminal can't. If use Mac then `export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:port` if windows then `set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:port`

Comment: Hi, There was some error in SSL and in creating web service. The above code is working fine now. Thanks.